# Kotlin .toInt() returns ASCII value

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on a 3 track step sequencer, and the spinners for sample selection are causing me some trouble. The following code is executed when a saved pattern is loaded to set the correct samples.

```
for ((index, j) in spinners.withIndex()){
   val item = loadingPattern[(48+index)]
   Log.i("item", item.toString())
   Log.i("int", item.toInt().toString)
   j.setSelection(item.toInt())
}
```

The array "spinners" contains 3 spinners with 5 entries each. "loadingPattern" is a string that contains the pattern information. The last three characters are integers corresponding to the spinner position. When the spinner selections are as the following:

Spinner 1: Selected item index 0
Spinner 2: Selected item index 3
Spinner 3: Selected item index 4

The log "item" prints exactly these values. The log "int" however prints 48+index, so in this case 48, 50, 52. Since the toInt() function is also called on the value parsed to the .setSelection() function, this exception is triggered:

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=48`

If anyone has an idea why this is happening, I would be very happy to know. Thank you all so much! I love this communtiy!

edit:
If the pattern is programmed like this:
[typical pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZvFl.png)

The "patternString" is the following:
101010101010101010000000100000001000100010001000420

active steps are represented by 1, the others by 0. The last 3 digits are the spinner positions. Maybe this will help :)

Edit 2:
I just found this question: [I have String with numbers when getting the char from string it shows '0'48 in kotlin. How to get the char alone in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52399443/12092346)
And there they say that the ASCII value of 0 is 48. **This means that toInt() probably returns the ASCII value of 0. But why is that and how can I get just the normal integer?**

Comment: Show me your "loadingPattern" string.

Answer (score 3):

I found it out!

As stated in [this](https://blog.jdriven.com/2019/10/converting-char-to-int-in-kotlin/) article, the `toInt()` function only works for strings and indeed returns the ASCII value of chars. The correct way of doing this is using `Character.getNumericValue()`.

Comment: If `loadingPattern` is a String, then `loadingPattern[i]` returns a `Char`. Char is a numeric type, so its `toInt()` method just does coercion (as opposed to `String.toInt()`, which calls through to `Integer.parseInt()`).